# Dell Dimension 8400 error

Tags: bios, hardware-failure, post

I've got an old Dell Dimension 8400 that's occasionally getting this error:

```
I\O card parity interrupt at C000:2100
Type (S)hut off NMI, (R)eboot, other keys to continue
```

The keyboard don't work so I have to force shutdown to reboot it.

Sometimes it does it again immediately after I reboot, sometimes it doesn't.

This seems to happen before POST, so i'm guessing a part is failing. How can I figure out which part?

Comment: What is your motherboard model?

Comment: @DaveRook According to CPU-Z it's by Dell Inc. Model # is 0U7077

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error has to do with an expansion card of some sort. If there are any expansion cards (video, USB, sound, etc.) installed, remove them one at a time to see if the error goes away.

If there are no expansion cards installed, or you've removed them all and still get the error, it is likely a motherboard problem.